# Waiting for the result of 2 asynchronous API calls before performing an operation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, asynchronous

I have 2 asynchronous API calls triggered on page load. I'm totaling the values returned in each of them and then calculating their % change. So I need to ensure that each API has successfully been called and that both the variables that hold the totals have been populated before calculating the difference.

What I've done now is to use `$watchGroup` to watch both the variables and call the function when both variables are not `null`.This is my controller code:

```
module Controllers {
    export class MyController {
        static $inject = ["$scope",'$http'];
        public TotalCurrent: any;
        public TotalPrevious: any;
        public diffPercent:any;
        constructor(
            private $scope: ng.IScope,
            private $http: ng.IHttpService,
        ) {
            this.$scope.$watchGroup(['myC.TotalCurrent', 'myC.TotalPrevious'], function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
                if (newVal[0] != oldVal[0] && newVal[1] != oldVal[1] && newVal[0] != null && newVal[1] != null)
                    scope.myC.diffPercent = scope.myC.GetDifferencePercent(newVal[0], newVal[1]);
            });
                this.GetValuesFromAPI();
        }


        public GetValuesFromAPI() {
            this.TotalCurrent = null;
            this.TotalPrevious= null;


            this.$http.get("url1").then((result: any) => {
                if (result.value.length > 0) {
                    var TempCurrentTotal = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
                        TempCurrentTotal += result.value[i].Val;
                    }
                    this.TotalCurrent = TempCurrentTotal;
                }

            });

            this.$http.get("url2").then((result: any) => {
                    if (result.value.length > 0) {
                        var TempPreviousTotal = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
                            TempPreviousTotal += result.value[i].Val;
                        }
                        this.TotalPrevious= TempPreviousTotal;
                    }
                })
        }

        public GetDifferencePercent(current:any, last:any){
            var percentage = ((Math.abs(current - last) / last) * 100).toFixed(2);
            return percentage;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine for now. However, I was wondering if there is any way to achieve this without having to worry about the performance issues associated with using  `$watchGroup` as the number of API calls is likely to increase in the future and my page has several other variables on `$watch`. I considered chaining the API calls with `.then()` but each API has a significantly large response time and chaining them would also slow down the page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered starting them in parallel?

You can use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) like this:

```
const promise1 = this.$http.get("url1");
const promise2 = this.$http.get("url2");

this.$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(results => {
  // results[0] is the result of the first promise, results[1] of the second.
});
```

You can inject $q service in your class constructor.

Callback is called when both promises are completed. You can also check for errors if you need it, just append a catch.